# Rayleigh quotient, traces and LDA optimization problem

Tags: optimization, matrix, discriminant-analysis

I've been working about Linear Discriminant Analysis the last weeks, and after reading many articles, I see some aspects of this problem not very clear.

The LDA optimization problem is formulated by defining the within-class ($S_w$) and between class ($S_B$) scatter matrices, and, despite the solution proposed everywhere consists in taking the eigenvectors of $S_{w}^{-1}S_B$ (let's assume that the matrices are regular enough to talk about inverses), the problem formulations I have seen are different and some of them don't seem to lead to that solution.

For example, one of the formulations consists in finding a matrix $U = (u_1,\dots,u_r)$, where $u_i$ are column vectors, whose vectors maximize the generalized Rayleigh quotient sum,
$$ R(U) = \sum_{i=1}^r \frac{u_i^TS_Bu_i}{u_i^TS_wu_i}$$

In this case, there exist a regular matrix $P$ so that $P^TS_BP = D$ is diagonal and $P^TS_wP = I$, and we can convert the generalized Rayleigh quotient sum in a common Rayleigh quotient sum,
$$ r(U) = \sum_{i=1}^r \frac{y_i^TDy_i}{y_i^Ty},$$
where $u_i = P^{-1}y_i$, so there is a bijective correspondence between both quotients. The second problem leads to the general PCA optimization problem
$$ \max_{U^TU = I} tr(U^TDU) ,$$
for which I know how to find the solution (in this case, the leading elements of the canonical basis, since $D$ is diagonal), and after applying $P$, we obtain the eigenvectors of $S_w^{-1}S_b$.

However, I usually find LDA with this trace optimization problem:
$$ \max tr((U^TS_wU)^{-1}(U^TS_BU)), $$
and in this case I can't rewrite this as a Rayleigh quotient sum. A still more different problem is the following one, for which I don't expect to have the same solution as the others, but anyways it is usually mentioned in LDA explanations:

$$\max \frac{tr(U^TS_BU)}{tr(U^TS_wU)}. $$

Even sometimes the trace is substituted by a determinant. So, which of these problems really lead to the solution of taking the eigenvectors of $S_w^{-1}S_B$?

Comment: OK. I think you can use the same bi-diagonalization change of coordinates to deal with the first trace optimization problem. Then you will see that it has the same LDA solution (i.e. is equivalent to the R. quotient). Other objectives that you list in the end are different. They do not correspond to the standard LDA.

Comment: But in this case the problem we obtain is $\max tr( (U^TU)^{-1} (U^TDU))$. From here can we reach the problem $\max_{U^TU = I} tr(U^TDU)$? For an individual Rayleigh quotient I see the equivalence of maximizing $x^TDx/(x^Tx)$ and maximizing $x^TDx$ subject to $x^Tx = 1$, but when matrices are involved I don't see this clear.

Comment: Well in the body of your question you use $U^\top U= I$ (third centered equation).

Comment: Yes, but the fourth equation doesn't lead to the third after bidiagonalizing.

Comment: When you say "The second problem leads to the general PCA optimization problem" and then write U'U=I in the following equation, then why is that? And why can't you apply the same reasoning when you bi-diagonalize the trace?

Comment: That's a consequence of Courant-Fischer theorem. But after bidiagonalizing you obtain $tr((U^TU)^{-1}(U^TDU))$. With Courant-Fischer I can make the step [maximize rayleigh quotient]->[maximize trace subject to $U^TU=I$]. Nothing is told about [maximize $tr((U^TU)^{-1}(U^TDU))$] -> [maximize trace subject to $U^TU=I$], so the equivalence I'm looking for is not proved.

Comment: Hey, I was on vacations. Will try to look into this.